# Differences between out_of_range, range_error, and over/underflow_error?

Tags: c++, exception, outofrangeexception

Could someone explain what the differences between `range_error`, `out_of_range`, and the pair of `overflow_error` and `underflow_error` are, when I should use each? They seem all like the same thing.

According to [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception):

- `out_of_range`:  It reports errors that are consequence of attempt to access elements out of defined range.
- `range_error`: It reports errors that arise because floating point value in some computation could not be represented because it was too large or too small in magnitude. If the value has integral type, `std::underflow_error` or `std::overflow_error` should be used.
- `overflow_error`: It reports errors that arise because integer value in some computation could not be represented as it had too large positive value.

Specifically, I have a function,

```
template<typename T>
void write_integer(const T &n) {
   if(n < 0) { throw ??? }
   if(some_limit < n) { throw ??? }
```

Where `T` is an integral type; the function does some bounds-checking on `n`, to see if it's within a certain range; if it isn't, I'd like to throw some exception. I'm confused because:

- `out_of_range` sounds like it's for indexing and array-bounds checking, which I'm not doing.
- `range_error` appears to be for floats? (But why, in a language like C++?)
- `underflow_error` and `overflow_error`? Are these really appropriate?

Comment: Out-of-range = input value makes no sense. All the rest = output value or intermediate value cannot be represented. You may want to consider std::domain_error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the standard:

`range_error`: The class range_error defines the type of objects thrown as exceptions to report **range errors in internal computations**.

`out_of_range`: The class out_of_range defines the type of objects thrown as exceptions to report an **argument value not in its expected range**.

`overflow_error`: The class overflow_error defines the type of objects thrown as exceptions to report an **arithmetic overflow error**.

`underflow_error`: The class underflow_error defines the type of objects thrown as exceptions to report an **arithmetic underflow error**.

For your function the most appropriate would be `out_of_range`.

Answer (score 5):

I have not thought a lot about it, but my guidelines seem to be:

- `out_of_range` when my abstraction can be thought of as a series of buckets or pigeonholes (discrete), and I requested a non-existing bucket or pigeonhole. The chief example being requesting the fourth element of a three-element array (the slots in the array can be thought of as buckets).
- `range_error` when the requested operation does not make mathematical sense in the domain considered (for example, the square root of a negative number when dealing with a real domain).
- `overflow_error` and `underflow_error` when the result would exceed the capacity of the underlying type. For example: an integer number larger than what can be held my `int`.

Comment: I found your examples more helpful than the marked answer, especially in the case of `range_error`